# Problems running proguard for single jar - can't find java classes

Tags: java, jar, proguard

I'm trying to optimize jar using Proguard

My config:

```
    -injars       MyLib-1.0.jar
    -outjars      MyLib-1.0.proguard.jar
    -libraryjars  retrace.jar
    -libraryjars  guava-18.0.jar
    -printmapping MyLib.map

    -keep public class MyLib {
        public String myPublicCallEntryPoint(java.lang.String);
    }

    -keep public class * {
        public protected *;
    }

    -keepclassmembernames class * {
        java.lang.Class class$(java.lang.String);
        java.lang.Class class$(java.lang.String, boolean);
    }
```

Then I run it with: `java -jar proguard.jar @myconfig.pro -verbose`

Log output:

```
Initializing...
Note: the configuration refers to the unknown class 'String'
Note: the configuration refers to the unknown class 'java.lang.String'
Note: the configuration refers to the unknown class 'java.lang.Class'
Note: the configuration refers to the unknown class 'java.lang.String'
Note: the configuration refers to the unknown class 'java.lang.Class'
Note: the configuration refers to the unknown class 'java.lang.String'
```

Is there any way to prevent such thing? How do I tell proguard to recognize base java classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I've mistake `rt.jar` from JRE with retrace from proguard package.